# Array into datalist

Tags: jquery, html

Well, I was here again 2 days ago for the same issue, but it seems that it's still not working. So the task is to pass an array that it's fields are CSV data. I got an advice to to it like this:

```
<datalist id="stelios">

</datalist>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object`

// Loop through the FileList
        for (var i in files) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            $('#stelios').append('<option value=' + files[i] + '>');
        }
    }

document.getElementById('stelios').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

It seems that I don't get the data yet though. Any ides?

Comment: Do you have any clue what this code does?

Comment: Not so sure. I'm new to jquery. But, it initializes a datalist, then goes through the array of "files[]", and once it reads the data from the csv file it passes them into the array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `for( var i in files )`. This will loop through all values in `files`, as well as anything that has been added to the Object prototype. ([This is bad](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/)) You'll need to filter the output of this.

The next line contains `var reader = new FileReader();`. There doesn't seem to be any reference to this in your for loop, so delete it.

The next line is `$('#stelios').append('<option value=' + files[i] + '>');`. It creates a certain 'option' element and appends this to an element with an id of stelios. This seems to be correct. However, the value of this option element is set to `files[i]` without quotes... Which will most likely result into a mess. You need to change it to:

```
for( var i in files ) {
  if( files.hasOwnProperty( i )) {
    //Removed unneeded FileReader
    $('#stelios').append('<option value="' + files[i] + '">');
  }
}
```

I am assuming that you checked that `files` contains the data you expect it to contain. I have honestly no clue what you are trying to achieve with the onchange handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the useful comments that you have provided. The task is to read data from a csv file and save them on an array. Then this array has to be passed into the datalist. I'm using code from the JavaScript File API - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/   (Section: Reading files). It normally displays the data from the data file on the page once I select the csv file. So now I just have to add the for-loop that passes the array into the datalist I guess? Thanks again